# Is interface based callback/events ever used over delegates?

Tags: c#, interface, delegates

In Java, with no delegates, events are modeled with interface callbacks after the observer pattern. It strikes me that if working on a framework with more than half a dozen events, using delegates becomes a fairly verbose exercise.

As a Java developer who forgot his C#, I was wondering if there is EVER a valid reason to use interfaces for events or whether one should really ought to use delegates all over?

Answer (score 2):

If it always makes sense to react to multiple callbacks, then it would potentially make sense to use an interface. However, you might want to write some adapter methods to allow the interface to be implemented by providing delegates for some of the callbacks - just the ones you want.

This is how [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) works... almost no-one ever *really* implements [`IObserver<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449.aspx) - they use the `IObservable<T>.Subscribe` extension method which allows the caller to specify the `OnNext`, `OnCompleted` and `OnError` handlers via delegates.

That way you get the benefits of delegates (which are generally easier to specify than interfaces, due to lambda expressions etc) but also one consistent object to pass around which represents all the related callbacks.

Comment: Interesting... but still a little theoretical for me to grasp. So what would the approach, using delegates rather than the following callback definition:

    public interface IPluginEvents
    {
        void OnLoad(IPlugin plugin);
        void OnShow(IPlugin plugin);
        bool CanUnload(IPlugin plugin);
        void OnUnload(IPlugin plugin);
    }

Comment: Well, one option would be to have a class implementing the interface which took delegates in the constructor... or possibly had a fluent interface `WithLoadHandler(...).WithShowHandler(...)` etc where each call built a new instance of the class with the extra handler. Not sure. Heck, it could even just use normal events, and implement the interface by calling the event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are much more flexible.  Since there are no anonymous classes in C# (in the Java sense) you cannot easily implement interfaces inline.  Therefore, whenever an API requires that I implement an interface, I have to go out and write out that class, which, when contrasted with lambdas, forces me to separate logic physically further away from each other, which often decreases readability.